# Remove links to the comments section

Tags: php, comments, urls, links

I need to remove links to the comments section from every post and page on the site.  Links to comments look like this:

These links appear:

1. In the post's byline as a speech bubble icon with the number of comments, hyperlinked to the comments section. `https://example.com/post-title/#comments`
2. In the comments section itself, where each comment's date is hyperlinked to the individual post's URL, such as `https://example.com/post-title/#comment-1234`

I am using a child theme of a third-party theme called Newsmatic.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme functions file:

```
// This will occur when the comment is posted
function plc_comment_post( $incoming_comment ) {
 
    // convert everything in a comment to display literally
    $incoming_comment['comment_content'] = htmlspecialchars($incoming_comment['comment_content']);
 
    // the one exception is single quotes, which cannot be #039; because WordPress marks it as spam
    $incoming_comment['comment_content'] = str_replace( "'", '&apos;', $incoming_comment['comment_content'] );
 
    return( $incoming_comment );
}
 
// This will occur before a comment is displayed
function plc_comment_display( $comment_to_display ) {
 
    // Put the single quotes back in
    $comment_to_display = str_replace( '&apos;', "'", $comment_to_display );
 
    return $comment_to_display;
}
 
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'plc_comment_post', '', 1);
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'plc_comment_display', '', 1);
add_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'plc_comment_display', '', 1);
add_filter( 'comment_excerpt', 'plc_comment_display', '', 1);
```